# Recursive IndentedBlock with optional contents

Tags: python, indentation, pyparsing

IndentedBlock from pyparsing not dedenting

I am trying to write a parser in pyparsing that has a container that has optional contents, and I'm not getting the results I'm expecting.

Here's the simplest version that demonstrates my problem I could come up with:

```
from pyparsing import *
ident = Word(alphas)
value = Word(nums)
container = Forward()
container << (Group(ident + IndentedBlock(container | value)) | ident)

test = """\
A
    1
    B
    C
        2
"""

container.parse_string(test, parse_all=True).pprint()
```

What I'm getting is this:

```
[['A', ['1', ['B', [['C', ['2']]]]]]]
```

Which shows that the C is being treated as indented underneath the B, but it should be listed underneath the A.

What I'm expecting is this:

```
[['A', ['1', ['B'], ['C', ['2']]]]]
```

Am I doing this wrong? How could I get a container with optional contents in pyparsing using IndentedBlock?

I am using pyparsing 3.1.1

Comment: That doesn't look like the C being treated as indented to me. That just looks like the effect of the Group. Why do you have a Group?

Comment: Without the Group, I get output like this:

    `['A', ['1', 'B', ['C', ['2']]]]`

Not as many brackets, but it still looks like C is being treated like it's indented underneath B.

Comment: You get those brackets for the same reason you get the brackets around the entire output - they're for the `container`, not an `IndentedBlock`.

Comment: Looking at your desired output... it looks like maybe you want parsing a `container` to produce a list, no matter which side of the `|` it parses? Whereas your original effort produced a doubly-nested list for the left side, and no list for the right side. Removing the `Group` removes the unnecessary extra list for the left side, but the right side still doesn't produce a list.

Comment: Although, your "What I'm expecting" still has that extra list around the whole output, so maybe you have something else in mind.